# won't run, won't switch activities

Tags: android, webview, android-activity, manifest

I want to create a splash screen that will then move to the login/register screen. My code looks like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class AssaultTDActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.TimeOut();
}

public void TimeOut(){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean continueloop = true;
    long timenow;

    while (continueloop = true){
        timenow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (timenow - start > 5000){
            continueloop = false;
            this.GoToRegister();
        }
    }
}

public void GoToRegister(){
    Intent i = new Intent(AssaultTDActivity.this, register_activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class register_activity extends Activity {
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.register);

        }
}
```

and my manifest file is the following:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AssaultTDActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity class =".register_activity"  
        android:label="Log in" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        android:name=".register_activity" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

So am I doing something wrong here?
Also is there a command to "do events" while looping so you dot get stuck in a loop?

Comment: Have you checked all answers for this question: ['Application not Installed' Error on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4226132/562935)?

Comment: I have checked them all, and tried each of their solutions, and none of them worked.

Comment: Should this be `<uses-Activityk android:minActivitykVersion="8" />` `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />`?

Comment: I have changed it already and it still didn't work

Comment: it's still not correct in your question. Now you have `<uses-Activity android:minVersion="8" />`

Comment: I updated the Manifest above.  The eclipse will show that obvious error if I have them written wrong.

Comment: @Leon even `<uses-Activityk` to `<uses-sdk` ?

Comment: @Leon Actually, Eclipse will NOT catch that error, I just tried it myself. Not only do you still have "uses-Activity" instead of "uses-sdk" but you also have capitalized minSdkVersion incorrectly, you have "minSDKVersion"

Comment: This is what I have in my Manifest.xml <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

Comment: have you tried putting in a targetSdkVersion too? it's supposed to be optional but worth a shot...

Comment: Also, you do have a MainActivity class, right? You specify it in your manifest...

Comment: Did you just change the question completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you added so many activities, it will most likely be fixed if you add:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

So your main activity is the default activity and then the Android Launcher wont get tripped up.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Taken from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

> Activities will very often need to support the `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` so
>   that they can be found by `Context.startActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is the issue: looks like you may have had a find/replace mistake, this line in your manifest is wrong:

```
<uses-Activityk android:minActivitykVersion="8" />
```

Change it to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```