# Android APK not getting installed

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a basic Android app as an Internship. Created its APK and tried to run on my mobile by connecting it to the Laptop by USB cable and used as an emulator, it's working perfectly. My Android OS version is Oreo, I tried the same to do on Lollypop and still it's getting executed.

The problem arrives when I am sending that APK via e-mail and trying to directly install on the device, it's giving me this error

> There was Problem in Parsing the Package

I don't know what is happening as it is getting executed directly from Android Studio.I kept minimum SDK as 15.

Please help me out.

Comment: Just google it with `There was Problem in Parsing the Package android`, I'm sure you'll find a lot of answers.

Comment: I would deal with this by just installing directly from the laptop which has Android Studio and your build running on it.

Comment: before sending an apk through e-mail.First build the apk.Because in your device you already have installed the app.So if you send that apk it won't install.try buildin apk again and send that

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do before installing.

[Android Unsigned App not able to install on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401922/android-unsigned-app-not-able-to-install-on-device)

And I hope answers here do the help too.

[Cannot install signed apk to device manually, got error "App not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265897/cannot-install-signed-apk-to-device-manually-got-error-app-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Build --> Clean Project
2. Build --> Rebuild Project
3. Build --> Build APK(s)
4. Apk Dir: Project Dir/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/xxx.apk

or check your app name length.

Comment: No bro, it's still not working. Giving me the same error "There was a problem parsing the package"