# Application not installed when installing my app

Tags: android

I've created my app, first time I tried it on my phone it was working fine, but then I unistalled it and installed it again, it gives me this error Application not installed
here's my mainfest.xml.. I think it has something to do with my mainfest file... I've read questions related to my problem, but I couldn't find any duplicated activities.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zegoggles.smssync"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:description="@string/app_description"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1406"
    android:versionName="1.4.5" >

    <application
        android:name="App"
        android:backupAgent="PreferenceBackupAgent"
        android:description="@string/app_description"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="SmsSync"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- handle gmail oauth callbacks -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="gmail"
                    android:scheme="smssync" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <service
            android:name="SmsBackupService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="SmsRestoreService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="BackupBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.zegoggles.smssync.BACKUP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
            android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAI15zt2oJAvxMu4s5SaHisDyYsduKd2jq_-XnAug" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BACKUP" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: check what the message in logcat says when you install the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the suggestions that are in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android)?

The thing i would try first is: uninstall the app manually from your device and then install again. Maybe it is just not getting removed for some reason.