# "Application was not installed" Android devices error

Tags: android, manifest

I have an android application which works perfectly on an AVD using Android 2.3.3, but it fails to install on any devices available for me to test(Sony Ericsson XPeria running Android 2.3.3, LG Optimus running Android 2.3.7 and Samsung Galaxy Tab Android 4.0.3). The error is "Application was not installed". As far as I know it may be connected with incorrect manifest file of an application, so here goes my `AndroidManifest.xml` if it might help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hohlocola"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
            <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HohloColaActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I export my application **unsigned**.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing really special in your manifest file. However, you could try declaring the `android:targetSdkVersion` attribute explicitly. Also, make sure that your test phones have the appropriate developer settings enabled; e.g. allow the installation of non-market apps, USB debugging etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot install an unsigned APK on a real device, you must export the APK using a valid key.  This can even be the same keystore/key that you use in debug mode, which is located (by default) at `~/.android/debug.keystore` or `C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore` and has a password of `android` for both the keystore and included key.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Android apps must be signed. See the [Android App Signing docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at logcat. My problem was in wrong permissions. I defined *android.permission.INTERNET* in *application* tag instead of separate *uses-permission*. Logcat output raises exception when you try to start app:

```
E/Launcher(  136): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: <...> requires android.permission.INTERNET
```

So try to find out what prevents your app from starting using adb logcat.

I've read this post too ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android) and there are lots of possibiliteis. Someone even have had to update Java.