# Application not Installed' Error on Android 2.3.4

Tags: java, android, debugging, apk

I have a program working in the Android Emulator. Every now and again I have been creating a `.apk` and exporting it to my *SonyEricsson Xperia* active to test. I have face the error **Applicton not install.**

I have tried rebooting the phone & removing the existing `.apk,` does not fix fault

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.note"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NoteActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NoteActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".NoteActivity1"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".NoteActivity2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Many thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: in your manifest, `minSdkVersion` is set to which value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Remove this

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

> and also remove this

```
 <activity android:name=".NoteActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".NoteActivity1"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".NoteActivity2"></activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove this code:

   ```
   <supports-screens
       android:largeScreens="true"
       android:normalScreens="true"
       android:smallScreens="true"/>
   ```

   All of these attributes are `true` by default anyway.
2. Also, take out this code:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".NoteActivity"></activity>
   ```

   You have already declared an `Activity` in your manifest with the exact same name. I believe this duplicate tag is the reason why your application is crashing.