# "Application not installed" Error on Android

Tags: android, installation

I am developing an application and my application is installed and tested successfully on emulator and lots of devices like Asus eee pad, Galaxy tab, Galaxy note, HTC …

But I can not install it on **Pidion BM-170** with android 2.3.7 and get error "Application not installed"

I tested other applications on this device and they are installed successfully. So the problem is about my application and this Pidion device.

I have signed my application.
I have tested putting `android:installLocation="auto"` in manifest.
I have tested Debuggable=false and true in manifest.
There is no previous application on device.

But I still get error "Application not installed".

I use these features in my application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Why I get this error? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you check the logcat, when you install/launch the application to see if you get errors ?

Comment: I could not do it yet. Because of device driver problem.

Comment: Maibe you have this issue only in that device. Try another device.

Comment: If you cannot access LogCat, how are you installing this app? When you examined LogCat using an on-device app like aLogCat, what did you find? Does your app use any firmware libraries, like Google Maps?

Comment: It is obvious. I have to use it.

Comment: Can you install with sdcard removed?

Comment: My PC can detect the SD card of the device and I can copy my APK to it. But DDMS does not show my device.

Comment: DDMS shows other devices correctly.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I am using Google Maps

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using Google Maps but why I get error only on this device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps that device does not have the Google Maps SDK add-on library. After all, [according to the device manufacturer, it does not even have Android normally](http://www.mypidion.com/product/product_tab.asp?t_idx=16&bmenu=1) -- it is described as "optional". They probably did not license the Google commercial apps, such as Play Store, YouTube, Google Maps, etc. If so, you cannot write apps that rely upon the Google Maps SDK add-on library that will run on that device.

Comment: OK thanks!!! I removed Google map, its library and `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` from my project and problem solved and program installed successfully.