# Why does android:deploy show success although there isn't any app on my device deployed?

Tags: android, maven, m2e

I have huge problems installing my signed app to my phone device (although it works on my tablet). 'Application not Installed' is my basic problem, see also this thread: ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android). I didn't come to a conclusion yet.
When I try to install the app from webserver I get an 'Application not Installed'. So I tried to install it by USB to get at least some error messages. android:deploy tells me

> Successfully installed
>   /path/to/workspace/target/kurzparkzonenwien-1.0-SNAPSHOT.apk to
>   MY_PHONE_ZTE-BLADE.

But there is no app on the phone. So is android:deploy buggy or do I need to set anything special? I execute it from Eclipse by launcher with goal android:deploy.

**[UPDATE]**
I think I know what's going on. LogCat shows me something....

```
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165): Exception reading /data/app/vmdl60304.tmp
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165): java.lang.SecurityException: /data/app/vmdl60304.tmp failed verification of META-INF/ANDROIDR.SF
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:350)
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:273)
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:416)
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadCertificate
```

Comment: Make sure that the phone isn't in some special 'Safe mode'. I had to reboot the phone into normal mode to see the app when I accidentally started up the phone that way.

Comment: Have you ticked the box "Unknown sources" in Settings -> Security? ( allow installation of apps from sources other than the Play Store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that something went wrong in signing.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the APK using command

> adb install -r yourApp.apk

here -r option is to replace the app if it exists.

Also, this link will help [ADB command](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: I get INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION, but see my updated question.