# Signing android app by Maven causes "App not installed"

Tags: android, maven, code-signing, jar-signing

I used these Maven settings to sign my app:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sign</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>signing</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <inherited>true</inherited>
                            <configuration>
                                <archiveDirectory></archiveDirectory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>target/*.apk</include>
                                </includes>
                                <keystore>/home/markus/.android/release.keystore</keystore>
                                <storepass>mypass</storepass>
                                <keypass>mypass</keypass>
                                <alias>androidreleasekey</alias>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>-sigalg</argument>
                                    <argument>MD5withRSA</argument>
                                    <argument>-digestalg</argument>
                                    <argument>SHA</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <sign>
                            <debug>false</debug>
                        </sign>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I took this info from here: http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/SigningAPKWithMavenJarsigner. But I always got this error message "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION" while deploying the app to my mobile phone (Android 2.1) and "App not installed" on the phone. I tried these suggestions described here (and even more): ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android). But none of these solutions worked for me. LogCat shows me this error:

```
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165): java.lang.SecurityException: /data/app/vmdl60304.tmp failed verification of META-INF/ANDROIDR.SF
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:350)
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:273)
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:416)
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadCertificates(PackageParser.java:317)
12-27 21:01:28.177: W/PackageParser(1165):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificate
```

After tinkering around half a day I figured out that this profile shown above somehow destroys the signature. When I add this part to my usual build section:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
            <sign>
                <debug>false</debug>
            </sign>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

to **NOT sign** the app while Maven install and sign the app by hand, it works:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /home/markus/.android/release.keystore myapp-1.0.apk androidreleasekey
```

I'm glad that I could manage it somehow, but can anybody explain to me why it doesn't work with Maven's sign profile on my smartphone? And what is interesting: **I was always able to install it on my tablet, Android 3.0, even with Maven**. Why does it work with Maven on Android 3.0 Galaxy Tab and not on my Android 2.1 phone?

By the way: A **debug deployment always worked**, even on my smartphone.