# Android application not installed error

Tags: android

This old chestnut again, 
After a lot of searching the best thread I found on this is  ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android)
In my case I  have checked all the fixes mentioned but still have the problem when I try to install the unsigned APK file. 
The app runs fine on my phone when I install it from Eclipse,  but when I put it on google drive and then point my phone to the APK I get the error above.  I have a Note 1
I have uninstalled the old app, reset my phone etc but no luck.  It worked fine for me until today,  I would just put the APK on google drive and install it from there and it worked each time,  just stopped working today and I have changed nothing.
I have both signed and Unsigned versions of the APK

Here is my manifest file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.app.nquizitive"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

        <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.app.nquizitive.StartupActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: how are you generating the "unsigned" apk? From within Eclipse, you'd actually be generating a signed apk, albeit with a debug signature that requires you to allow to install apk's from unknown sources.

Comment: Might be obvious, but I have had issues with my S3 not remembering some developer settings after reboot.  With that in mind, you might wanna check the "Allow unknown sources" is still checked or try toggling it

Comment: I suspect that you have an apk on your device with same package name with a higher version code or with a different signature. Try to uninstall your apk with adb(not from app manager on your device): adb uninstall com.app.nquizitive. After this retry to install and share result.

Comment: You cannot install an **unsigned** apk, period.  Presumably, you mean a debug-signed one.

Answer (score -1):

My devices will only load signed APKs under these conditions. It appears to be a case of Google's boot on our neck. So I'm not sure what an unsigned one is good for unless you load it on a $45 USD Google-free device from China. So I release signed ones with increasing version numbers but with version "1" google-wise and then release "1"/"1.0" on Google Play.

Comment: Have just downloaded my apk to a htc one x and it runs fine. Same file gives me the error message when i instal it on a galaxy note.

Comment: Maybe its Samsung's boot on our neck. Both of my devices are Samsung.