# trying without success to install my android app on my note2

Tags: android, eclipse

I can debug and run on handset with no problems when running the app through eclipse but I cannot install it on the phone
I thought it was to do with my certificate and the fact I didn't have one - I now have one but its still not installing.
I have set the device to install app from unknown sources and I have went to my workspace and copied the apk file onto the device - the app looks like its installing but when I click its icon it says "application not installed"
What I would like to do clear my keystore and any settings and start again.
I've created a keystore with out error for this app and then I run it and then I try to drop the apk. file into the device then open from there with 'my files'. 
I do realise this is a popular question and I have tried the other answers but I'm still having a problem
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Debug it on your phone.  Once you debug the app it is installed on the device.  It might not leave a quick launcher so look in your list of apps for it.

Comment: Thanks Danny the icon is present but when I click on it it just says application not installed.  The app also shows in my list of apps and i can un install it

Comment: I've found another instance of this question with many more answers, I'll update my question when I resolve my version of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: I found what was causing my problem - it was my manifest file and I had permissions entry in with the application parameters. I would have hoped for an error message but there ye go. I recommend the above link for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing my problem - it was my manifest file and I had permissions entry in with the application parameters. I would have hoped for an error message but there ye go. I recommend the link below for this issue.