# App Not Installed error

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have created an unsigned apk for my nexus 7. When I try and install it, the device pops up with, "App Not Installed". In the Eclipse emulator everything works fine. I have tried to alter my target to 4.2,4.3,4.4. Again, all work in the emulator but not on the device, the device is running 4.3.

Comment: Do you have Settings -> Security -> Device Administration -> Unknown sources checked?

Comment: Yes I do have it checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An unsigned application cannot be installed. You should sign it with jarsigner tool (provided by Android SDK tools)

> The important points to understand about signing Android applications
>   are:
>
> - All applications must be signed. The system will not install an    application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed.

See http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: If it's working on your emulator, it's because Eclipse sign your application with a debug key.

Comment: In the bin folder, the debug apk exists, there shouldn't be a problem with trying to install that on the device I'm guessing?

Comment: Just tried it, it worked, awesome. Not sure if there are any reason why one shouldn't use that method though.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to solve this

1.Signing the apk (which is preferable)

2.Take apk from bin instead of taking unsigned then instead of replacing the app, un-install existing app and install it