# Application not installed error on real devices

Tags: android

I have an android app that is running on [Genymotion emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/)(Google Nexus 5 -4.4.2). But it does not get installed on any of the real devices I have tried so far (All of them between 2.3 to 4.0).

I have tried all the solutions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android) question.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vishal.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityEventsList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_events_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityEventDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_event_details" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Project build target is 4.4.2 (API 19). I am installing the app from apk file copied to SD card.

Here's my logcat:

```
08-18 22:50:49.964: I/ActivityManager(249): START {dat=file:///sdcard/app.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity} from pid 3626
08-18 22:50:49.974: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(138): value of device and enable is 6 1
08-18 22:50:49.984: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.567504] [msm7x30.c:msm_device_put] device speaker_mono_rx set 1
08-18 22:50:49.984: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.567565] [msm7x30.c:msm_device_put] device freq =48000
08-18 22:50:49.994: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.575408] [adsp.c:msm_adsp_get] module AFETASK has been registered
08-18 22:50:49.994: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.575469] [adsp.c:msm_adsp_enable] enable 'AFETASK'state[0] id[17227119]
08-18 22:50:49.994: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.582550] [adsp.c:adsp_rtos_mtoa_cb] rpc event=0, proc_id=2, module=17227119, image=0
08-18 22:50:49.994: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.582611] [adsp.c:adsp_rtos_mtoa_cb] module AFETASK: READY
08-18 22:50:50.044: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.623260] msm_snddev_poweramp_on: power on amplifier
08-18 22:50:50.044: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.623474] [adsp.c:msm_adsp_get] module AUDPPTASK has been registered
08-18 22:50:50.044: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.623535] [adsp.c:msm_adsp_enable] enable 'AUDPPTASK'state[0] id[17227122]
08-18 22:50:50.044: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.626739] [adsp.c:adsp_rtos_mtoa_cb] rpc event=0, proc_id=2, module=17227122, image=0
08-18 22:50:50.044: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.626800] [adsp.c:adsp_rtos_mtoa_cb] module AUDPPTASK: READY
08-18 22:50:50.044: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.632873] [audpp.c:audpp_dsp_event] ENABLE
08-18 22:50:50.054: D/kernel(129): [ 4310.637115] [adsp.c:msm_adsp_write] AUDPPTASK command took 64 attempts: rc 0
08-18 22:50:50.074: I/eFrame(3639): pkgname_before:com.apkinstall  class:com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity
08-18 22:50:50.214: W/InputManagerService(249): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2c655218 (uid=10126 pid=3626)
08-18 22:50:50.284: I/ActivityManager(249): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: +263ms
08-18 22:50:50.514: D/SurfaceFlinger(121): Release buffer at 0x97b98
08-18 22:50:51.594: I/ActivityManager(249): START {dat=file:///sdcard/app.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras)} from pid 3295
08-18 22:50:51.784: D/dalvikvm(3295): GC_CONCURRENT freed 296K, 4% free 9229K/9607K, paused 6ms+4ms
08-18 22:50:51.804: I/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(138): Routing audio to Speakerphone
08-18 22:50:51.844: W/ActivityManager(249): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///sdcard/app.apk
08-18 22:50:51.994: I/ActivityManager(249): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress: +363ms
08-18 22:50:52.124: D/OpenGLRenderer(3295): Flushing caches (mode 0)
08-18 22:50:52.214: W/ActivityManager(249): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///sdcard/app.apk
08-18 22:50:52.224: D/SurfaceFlinger(121): Release buffer at 0x5d5b8
08-18 22:50:52.234: E/PackageParser(249): Package com.vishal.app has no certificates at entry assets/jsondata.txt; ignoring!
08-18 22:50:52.284: E/SemcSettingsParser(3711): key not found. key=[brand]
08-18 22:50:52.284: E/SemcSettingsParser(3711): key not found. key=[group-visible]
```

Comment: Post your logcat when trying to install the app in other device..Have you installed the app using adb or manually?

Comment: I have installed the app via sdcard

Comment: But how? I mean via copying and pasting apk then installing Or using android debugger bridge? Be case If you've used latter approach post your logcat!!

Comment: @PrashantPatel Even if you copied the apk to the SD card and then installed it from SD card, the device's logcat would have the details.  Connect the device to a computer and issue `adb logcat` on it.

Comment: Try to install it using the adb. right click on project then run as  -> android application.

Comment: Your Manifest file looks Fine. there must be some different error.

Comment: @PrashantPatel  G I have added logcat to my question. Please see

Comment: @AleksG please see the logcat