# Mobilefirst application apk file not installing in real devices

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

i am using mobilefirst platform for hybrid application development.

I created an application in and created .apk file of this application:
Generated Android project folder -> Android tools -> Export unassigned application

I then copied this apk file to android device and try to install this .apk file. At this time its showing `Application not installed`.

It's properly working in simulator and browser.
What is the issue here?

Comment: There are some answers for the same error message in this other so answer in case you haven't read it yet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: Provide LogCat output from the installation time period.

Comment: Also, did you try to simply select "run on android device" instead of export the apk? does it work?

Comment: I just do the "run on android device" that's working fine. But the export .apk file installation is not working on android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that you have exported an `unsigned application`, which is not intended for distribution purposes.
Try Exporting a signed application package, by following one of the following steps :

1. "`Right click project -> Export -> Export Android Application`"
2. "`Right click project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package`"

Both of the above methods will export a `signed application file`, used for distribution purposes.

**You may also test your app on a real device by just connecting your device to the testing machine via a USB cable and then following step below :**

`Right Click on your Project root` -> Go to `Run As` -> Select `Android Application` -> Now a popup is shown with all the `active devices` -> `Select your device` from the list

**

### Newbie Guide to Export Signed Application and configuring keystore file in Eclipse :

1. "`Right click project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package`"
2. A popup as shown below would appear, if your project won't contains any erros :

[image]

3. Click `Next`
4. On clicking Next, you'll get a screen as shown below :

[image]

5.On this screen, make sure `Create new keystore` is checked.
6.`Browse` to the location, you want to create a new `keystore` at, and also add a password to access it later.
7.Then Click `Next`
8.On clicking next you'll get a screen as shown below :

[image]

9.Fill all the fields in this screen, (ONLY first five are mandatory), In validity fill the number of years this key would be valid for, then click `Next`.
10.On clicking Next you'll get a screen as shown below :

[image]

11.Browse to the location you want to keep for apk file in, and Click `Finish`, and you are done!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Via USB cable its working perfectly!. Signed application package needs keystore. I am not familiar to configure the keystore for signed package...

Comment: Let me know if you want to know anything else!

Comment: I just give the location for new keystore and password but the next or finish button is not come to active.It needs any app store credential or something like that

Comment: As I said in step 6, you will need to create a new password for your keystore as well as alias!

Comment: I just export through the signed package that resolve my issue !!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a Signed application package rather than an Unsigned application package?

It could be that in your device settings (under Security) you have not allowed to install applications from Unknown Sources.

1. Enable support for Unknown Sources
2. Try again with an unsigned package

When you select Run As > Run on Android device", the application gets signed with the debug keystore supplied by Android, so it's still a "signed" package.

Comment: I didn't tried with Signed application package.I just tried with Unsigned application package. And also I enabled Support for unknown sources but its still showing "Application not installed".