# Android application not installed on device error

Tags: android

I have an application that I have created on Eclipse. However, when I run this application, the widget is not appearing on the home screen. So, the only way to run the application is by connecting it via a USB cable and running it through the software, so I am unable to use the application on the move.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sunveersinghseera.wardrobematcher"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sunveersinghseera.wardrobematcher.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sunveersinghseera.wardrobematcher.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Camera"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_camera" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Gallery"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Favourites"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favourites" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Categories"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categories" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewHelp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_viewhelp" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Contact"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactImageAdapter"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contactimageadapter" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CustomListAdapter"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customlistadapter" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DataBaseHandler"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_databasehandler" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_displayimageactivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SQLiteDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sqlitedemoactivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CategorySmart"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categorylistsmart" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CategoryAccessory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categorylistaccessories" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CategoryCasual"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categorylistcasual" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CategoryFood"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categorylistfood" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CategoryFootwear"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categorylistfootwear" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CategoryGoingOut"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categorylistgoingout" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CategorySport"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categorylistsport" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialVideo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tutorialvideo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HelpGallery"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cameragalleryhelp" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HelpFavourites"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favouritehelp" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HelpColourPicker"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_colourpickerhelp" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HelpCategories"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categorieshelp" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoGallery"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallerytutorialvideo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoFavourites"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favouritestutorialvideo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoColorPicker"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_colorpickertutorialvideo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoCategories"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categoriestutorialvideo" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does any of the `<activity>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` have a `<intent-filter>` child?

Comment: It would help by the way to post your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sunveersinghseera.wardrobematcher"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" />

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sunveersinghseera.wardrobematcher.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sunveersinghseera.wardrobematcher.MainActivity" />

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Camera"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_camera" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Gallery"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Favourites"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favourites" >

Comment: </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Categories"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categories" >
        </activity>
 

</manifest>

Comment: You may want to just update your original post to contain the manifest file instead of putting it in the comments..

Comment: I have added in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the application is not compatible with your device or Android version running on the device itself.

Comment: But then the application wouldn't even run? Am I correct in saying that? I have uploaded my android manifest.

Comment: maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android