# APP not installed an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

i'm new to android development i have developed one application and distribute a copy from bin folder not in playstore . The user try to install app second time with different version it's giving  "APP not installed an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed" like this but same version it's not coming like this.

I want to install app without uninstalling(means user don't want to do uninstall) previous one without using play store and one more doubt when this signature will generates .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have already installed your application with signature and now you'r trying to install apk from bin folder then it will be sure ask to reinstall again with different signature but before that need to uninstall previous one.

Comment: Refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: Since signature is different, u should uninstall and install again or give with same signature which works without uninstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what happens: most probably you'd compiled a DEBUG version of app and distributed it your own way. At that time your IDE used a debug certificate which is auto created every time you install IDE/SDK. Now, some time has passed and you'd switched your working PC/notebook OR you'd reinstalled the IDE/SDK OR you'd switched lets say from Eclipse to AndroidStudio OR changed your OS from Win7 to Win8 or Ubuntu, no matter what you did but as a result the brand NEW debug certificate was generated and used now. And most probably you'd lost your previous debug certificate 4ever (depends how this happens).
The certificate itself stands for a unique fingerprint and each debug or release certificate has its own unique fingerprint. That fingerprint is the signature Android talking about. Every apk is signed using certificate and has its signature, its mandatory.
So, since you are using a different debug key store certificate you are NOT ABLE to do what you want. The right scenario is to create a release certificate (key store) and to sign you app with it and then distribute app any way you want. This way you should also save your release certificate and reuse it later to sign any upcoming updates.
As for now you should restore your certificate you'd signed your apk with or the only way your users has now is to uninstall and then install.

Answer (score 1):

Harsha Vardhan is right, You should first clean project and then use same signature with installed apk.

Answer (score 0):

what ever you said it's correct but the problem here is i have changed sdk because of this problem is occurred . I think solution is need to generate apk file from same sdk .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why that just happened.

But that's happened to me one time also.

I've changed my **package name** from **com.aashakil.myapp** to **com.myapp** and it was fixed.

If you change yours it'll may work.