# APK signed not installed

Tags: android

I created a apk with android studio and SDK 23, when I build in debug mode this is installed smoothly in the mobile and runs perfectly but when signed and compiled in release mode starts the installation process on the mobile but at the end I leaves the message "application not installed".

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['App not Installed' Error on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to difference in sign certyficates. 
Your debug apk is signed with developer certyficate and your release apk with different one.

**Solution** 
uninstal the debug apk befor instaling the release one.
There won't be any signing conflicts after that and the instalation should instal as smoth as the debug apk.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I uninstall the application unsigned and then the new one (signed) and worked perfectly