# Error while re-installing app on the device

Tags: android

I use the emulator for the development and then once the build is in stable position, i make a APK and install it on my device for testing purpose (app-debug.apk)

this has been working fine for sometime now.

The problem is lately i made another build and when i am trying to install it - it gives me `apk not installed` error

i tried multiple times but did not succeed. Since i had made some changes to the android manifest file (removed a broadcast listener) i thought that could be a issue and i put the code back.

but in both the cases i got the same result.

i finally had to uninstall the existing version and then install the new one.

Not sure what is really happening.  As in ideal world the app should have upgraded itself without any uninstall. Is there somewhere i can check the install logs ?

to Add - i have not made any changes to the database structure

Comment: How are you attempting to install it? I assume you're using "adb install", but could you give the full command-line? Is there any other output other than "apk not installed"? My guess is that you probably need to use "adb install -r apkname.apk" and you're missing the "-r".

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['App not Installed' Error on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Comment: I have read the above mentioned thread but did not work.  I have been doing this for some time now but this is the first time am faced the issue

Comment: @sheltond emulator is working fine. I made an apk and then transferred it using shareit, I have done this multiple times