# How to fix App not installed error in Android

Tags: android, android-signing

I develop android application and when create APk from this application (with `Generate Signed APK`) and when install this apk in other devices not install and show me this error on phone : **App not installed**

how can i fix it?

Comment: Check this one its similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4226132/6333971)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is usually caused when you have a debug apk that is signed with a different certificate and you are trying to install a release version with a different certificate. If you have a debug apk on the device try uninstalling it and try again.

Answer (score 8):

For me, `**disabling Google Play Protect**` options from play store app worked , and i was able to get rid of the App not Installed error.
Check the play protect option available in Google Play Store Navigation menu.

Answer (score 3):

**`android:extractNativeLibs="true"`**

in **`AndroidManifest.xml`** file fixed the problem for me.

```
    <application
        // ...
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
```

**Notes:** I got this error when building with App Center and all the signing was handled by app center.

**For easier debugging just drag and drop the `apk` file in the android emulator.
Your will get a more detailed message why the app is not installed.**

Previously I tried all the Play protect things and checked the `build.gradle` file contains no release info in signingConfigs and that there's no `signingConfig` in `buildTypes.release` just as described in the other answers from this page.

Comment: This seemed to work for me. I am trying to understand the drawback of this, if any? It seems like all this does is compress your native libs, but I can't tell if this has any unwanted side affects

Comment: This fix was recommended to me by AppCenter support team. I found more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998083/setting-androidextractnativelibs-false-to-reduce-app-size

Answer (score 1):

delete build folder from your project and then build project again.. working for me

Answer (score 0):

[File an appeal with Google Play Protect](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals)

[image]

**Proper way to create URL to download your APK file**

You need to make a direct link to download application, not to a drive.
First, I uploaded my application on google drive and shared the link.
after submitting the apeal I instantly received a mail

> Hi
>
> You recently submitted an appeal for an app with Google Play Protect.
>
> The link you have provided **does not lead to an APK file** or the file is
>   corrupted. Please submit a new appeal and check that you are providing
>   the link to the correct APK file.
>
> Thank You, Google Play Protect Team

- Upload your APK file to dropbox (didn't try any other platform)
- Get sharable link (link setting should be `Anyone with this link can view the file.`)
- Your link will something like this `https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxxxxx/ApplicationName.apk?dl=0`
- Change the ending `apk?dl=0` to `apk?dl=1` (Changing it to `0` will make the link to direct download the APK, try it yourself and see.)
- Your new link should be like this `https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxxxxx/ApplicationName.apk?dl=1`
- Use any [URL Shortner](https://bitly.com/)
- Your acceptable link is ready

**If you don't know what is your Application package name, then go to your `AndroidManifest.xml`** 
There will be line `package="com.example.MyApplication"`

After submitting it if everything goes correct you may receive a mail instantly from Google

> Hi
>
> You recently submitted an appeal for an app with Google Play Protect.
>
> We have successfully received the appeal for your app. Our team will
>   review the app and any information you have provided.
>
> Thank You, Google Play Protect Team

Don't expect any other reply from Google Play Protect Team, In my case, I didn't receive any mail, But the issue was solved, After a 2-3 business day the issue was fixed while installing the application I no longer received the `Blocked by Play Protect` warning. and `App not installed`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I have had the same "App not installed" issue that I have been struggling with, this is how I solved it.

Connect your device to your computer, and just before you start installing the app, run this command from commandline:

```
adb logcat > logcat.txt
```

And stop it right after you get the "App not installed" message. (Ctrl + c).

The reason for starting and stopping it just around the install process is because logcat is very "chatty".

Have a look in the generated text-file to find the error. It can be like finding the needle in a haystack, but I found my error just before "packageinstaller.InstallFailed" log-line.

The error looked like this:

```
10-10 21:36:43.402  1549  1940 E NativeLibraryHelper: Library 'libjsc.so' is not page-aligned - will not be able to open it directly from apk.
10-10 21:36:43.402  1549  1940 W NativeHelper: Failure copying native libraries [errorCode=-2]
10-10 21:36:43.403  1549  1940 E PackageInstallerSession: Commit of session 1728055717 failed: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by correct the targetSdkVersion from build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this issue, I monitored the Logcat and could see the error because my app was not installed.

I received message DOWNGRADE VERSION, added a VersionCode in BuildGradle and for me it's working.