# nativeLibraryDir appears empty after updating to Gradle 5.6.4 and Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, native

It appears that my libraries no longer exist in nativeLibraryDir after updating Gradle from 5.4.1 to 5.6.4 and Android Studio from 3.5.3 to 3.6.1.  My current implementation for accessing my libraries is as follows:

```
File libDirectory = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir);
String files[] = libDirectory.list();
```

Before the update, I can debug and see that the 'files' array contains a list of all my libraries as expected. 
After the update, the 'files' array appears empty.

I have analyzed my APK and confirmed that the libraries do exist in the package.

Am I retrieving the path in a poor fashion? Is there required permissions that I am not aware of? I am using CMake to build my libraries:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path '../../../common/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

Using NDK version 21.0.6113669

Update:
Reverting to NDK r19c produces the same results

Update: `libDirectory` resolves to */data/app/com.example.application-1/lib/arm* before and after the update

Update: setting `android.useNewApkCreator=false` in gradle.properties produces the same result

Update: Using the Device File Explorer, I am able to view the libraries within the lib/arm/ folder prior to the update. After the update, the lib/arm/ folder is still the same size (4KB), but I am no longer able to view the content within the folder. Folder permissions appear to be unchanged.

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: Same issue, following

Answer (score 8):

I also encountered this problem, and I finally solved it by :

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
<application
  ...
  android:extractNativeLibs="true"  
  ...
>
```

when `extractNativeLibs` set to `true`, `so files` copy to `lib/xxx` folder.

Comment: alse see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998083/setting-androidextractnativelibs-false-to-reduce-app-size/47541129

Answer (score -2):

use this version

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'

}
```

with Gradle 5.6.4

Comment: Issue still occurs with these versions