# Android, do average app need ndk and where are the built files?

Tags: android, react-native, android-ndk

The end goal is to figure out why our apps are crashing with `libc.so`

The following is from firebase crashlytics and we can't say what is causing the crash.

[image]

So I dig the crashlytics documentation but it seems we need to tell them where the object files (maybe they contain the symbols?) are

eg)

```
 strippedNativeLibsDir "$buildDir/ndklibs/obj"
 unstrippedNativeLibsDir "$buildDir/ndklibs/libs"
```

The paths set above namely `$buildDir/ndklibs/obj` doesn't exist in my system and I need to find the correct path..

What is my situation here? Below is What I think where I am.. but I'm not even sure..

> Our app (and any android app?) uses ndk (because maybe some libraries
> we use need ndk? we surely don't use native c/c++ code to build
> something)
>
> But we don't know know where the required ndk `obj` files are.
>
> To find that out, we need to go through `ndk` setup process and figure
> out where they place `obj` files are?

Comment: Just want to remove the obvious - your tag indicates the app is react-native, you should clarify what kind of app it is. Also other than the react-native runtime, are you using any plugins that have c/c++ libraries? A quick search shows this issue ticket: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29978

Comment: We use many libraries, so it will not surprise me if we have a library that uses c/c++ .. react native itself uses c/c++ no?

Comment: The idea is to identify where the problem is coming from: a plugin library, react native runtime or environment (device make/model/OS version) as the issue. Sadly those on that thread that I linked to also seem to be searching for reproducibility.

Comment: I want to see the  symbols first, you see all those `missing` in the picture I posted.. reproducibility is .. probably a later step..

Comment: the fact that I'm seeing libc.so in the bug report says I'm using `NDK`?

Comment: Possibly useful: [Unable to get stack trace for native crashes in Crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60778997/295004) which has a link to this issue ticket: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1700