# APK size increased 35mb when bumping min SDK from 21 to 24

Tags: android, apk, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-native-library, android-min-sdk

Recently we bumped our min supported SDK from API 21 to 24.

Apparently this change caused our APK size to increase from 65mb to 103mb.
From the APK analysis in Android studio, we can see it's all of the .so files that have basically doubled in size.

But why would that be? No gradle properties have changed, just the min sdk.

Any thoughts on how to decrease the APK size again?

Answer (score 39):

> But why would that be? No gradle properties have changed, just the min sdk.

According to [this answer on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/f9u9x4/apk_size_increased_2x_on_android_gradle_360/fiud804/) and [this issue on Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127691661) that's because starting with API 23 the platform can read native libraries without extracting them if they are uncompressed, so they changed the default value of `extractNativeLibs` manifest attribute.

If you declare minSdk 23 or higher, building the APK with uncompressed native libraries should save space on devices because:

- APK is compressed before download anyway, so download size doesn't change
- after installation, there's only one copy of the library (uncompressed inside APK)

When I just tested this, the size after installation was actually higher with minSdk 23 compared to 22, contrary to what they say should happen. That is [because the APK includes libraries for all ABIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541129/1916449). If I use only one ABI it is a bit smaller with minSdk 23.

> Any thoughts on how to decrease the APK size again?

So until you start [splitting the APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits) or use [App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) (which is pretty easy and can decrease the size even more), you may want to set [`android:extractNativeLibs="true"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs) in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to get the old behavior.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for adding a response to this.
Your solution is actually almost what I went with in the end - we set extract native libs true for debug builds and false otherwise. That way, debug apks stayed their original size (to work around upload limits for some tools) and release apks still take to take advantage of play store compression so end users download is smaller.