# apkanalizer - What can increase the raw file size of the native libs?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-native-library, apkanalyzer

I have a project that used to weight around 140MB. Then, something changed and new version of the app is increasing by 100MB the apk size, even when the download size remains mostly the same.

We did not do any major config modifications, but did increase the minSDKVersion. Is that what is impacting the file size? Or what could be impacting the raw sizes?

BEFORE

contents where RAW size is almost same as Download size:

[image]
[image]

AFTER
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [APK size increased 35mb when bumping min SDK from 21 to 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440105/apk-size-increased-35mb-when-bumping-min-sdk-from-21-to-24)