# ClassNotFoundException only when downloading from Google Play, using Android Studio 4.1.2 and Android Application Bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I have written an app, and have uploaded it to internal testing on Google Play.
Following Google's recommendation, this time I have gone with an Android Application Bundle instead of an APK.

When I download it from the Play store, it crashes immediately with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

If I run the app through Android Studio as a Default APK, it works fine.
If I run the app through Android Studio as "APK from app bundle", it also works fine.

My app has three modules. "app" is the main bit.  I have a 3d engine module named bulletspeed.  The missing class is from the bulletspeed module.  I don't know if the third module is missing classes yet, as the program hasn't advanced that far before crashing.

Is there some sort of module setting that I am missing?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, my issue was was with proguard. The classes were there all along, just renamed to c.c.b.a.wtf.etc

- During the build process, I serialize some 3D scenes into a Java ObjectOutputStream.
- In my program, I deserialize the scenes from OOS resources back into Objects
- Deserialization could not find the classes by name as the names were obfuscated

Following this guide, I was able to configure proguard rules so that I could deserialize normally: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't solve the issue but helps you with testing:

Download the bundletool from Google https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool and create apk from app bundle locally to test, so you won't need to create a bunch of internal app testings and wait...

1. create the app bundle (.aab) and locate the folder
2. `java -jar "bundletool-all-x.x.x.jar" build-apks --bundle="yourpathto.aab" --output="folderoutput.zip" --mode="universal"`
3. unzip the created zip package
4. install the general apk into your test device/emulator

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it definitely sped things up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try uncompressing native libs by default in your Android Manifest.

[Setting android:extractNativeLibs=false to reduce app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998083/setting-androidextractnativelibs-false-to-reduce-app-size/47541129)