Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:
i am using godot 4.3 beta and this problem comes when i exporting to android apk
 editor/export/editor_export_platform.h:182 - Export: Building of Android project failed, check output for the error:
  
  
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  
  * Where:
  Build file 'E:\Ahmed\godot\projects\‏‏ADMOB4.3\android\build\build.gradle' line: ?
  
  * What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:
  
  - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
  - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.5.0')
    Searched in the following repositories:
      Google
      MavenRepo
      Gradle Central Plugin Repository
      maven(https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/)
  
  * Try:
  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  > Run with --scan to get full insights.
  > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
  
  BUILD FAILED in 2s

here is full code of build.gradle :
// Gradle build config for Godot Engine's Android port.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

apply from: 'config.gradle'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }

        // Godot user plugins custom maven repos
        String[] mavenRepos = getGodotPluginsMavenRepos()
        if (mavenRepos != null && mavenRepos.size() > 0) {
            for (String repoUrl : mavenRepos) {
                maven {
                    url repoUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    // Initializes a placeholder for the devImplementation dependency configuration.
    devImplementation {}
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$versions.fragmentVersion"

    if (rootProject.findProject(":lib")) {
        implementation project(":lib")
    } else if (rootProject.findProject(":godot:lib")) {
        implementation project(":godot:lib")
    } else {
        // Godot gradle build mode. In this scenario this project is the only one around and the Godot
        // library is available through the pre-generated godot-lib.*.aar android archive files.
        debugImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs/debug', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
        devImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs/dev', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
        releaseImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs/release', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    }

    // Godot user plugins remote dependencies
    String[] remoteDeps = getGodotPluginsRemoteBinaries()
    if (remoteDeps != null && remoteDeps.size() > 0) {
        for (String dep : remoteDeps) {
            implementation dep
        }
    }

    // Godot user plugins local dependencies
    String[] pluginsBinaries = getGodotPluginsLocalBinaries()
    if (pluginsBinaries != null && pluginsBinaries.size() > 0) {
        implementation files(pluginsBinaries)
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion versions.buildTools
    ndkVersion versions.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility versions.javaVersion
        targetCompatibility versions.javaVersion
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = versions.javaVersion
    }

    assetPacks = [":assetPacks:installTime"]

    namespace = 'com.godot.game'

    defaultConfig {
        // The default ignore pattern for the 'assets' directory includes hidden files and directories which are used by Godot projects.
        aaptOptions {
            ignoreAssetsPattern "!.svn:!.git:!.gitignore:!.ds_store:!*.scc:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
        }

        ndk {
            String[] export_abi_list = getExportEnabledABIs()
            abiFilters export_abi_list
        }

        manifestPlaceholders = [godotEditorVersion: getGodotEditorVersion()]

        // Feel free to modify the application id to your own.
        applicationId getExportPackageName()
        versionCode getExportVersionCode()
        versionName getExportVersionName()
        minSdkVersion getExportMinSdkVersion()
        targetSdkVersion getExportTargetSdkVersion()

        missingDimensionStrategy 'products', 'template'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'MissingTranslation', 'UnusedResources'
    }

    ndkVersion versions.ndkVersion

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

        // 'doNotStrip' is enabled for development within Android Studio
        if (shouldNotStrip()) {
            doNotStrip '**/*.so'
        }

        jniLibs {
            // Setting this to true causes AGP to package compressed native libraries when building the app
            // For more background, see:
            // - https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-3-6-0-release-notes#extractNativeLibs
            // - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704840
            useLegacyPackaging shouldUseLegacyPackaging()
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            if (hasCustomDebugKeystore()) {
                storeFile new File(getDebugKeystoreFile())
                storePassword getDebugKeystorePassword()
                keyAlias getDebugKeyAlias()
                keyPassword getDebugKeystorePassword()
            }
        }

        release {
            File keystoreFile = new File(getReleaseKeystoreFile())
            if (keystoreFile.isFile()) {
                storeFile keystoreFile
                storePassword getReleaseKeystorePassword()
                keyAlias getReleaseKeyAlias()
                keyPassword getReleaseKeystorePassword()
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            // Signing and zip-aligning are skipped for prebuilt builds, but
            // performed for Godot gradle builds.
            zipAlignEnabled shouldZipAlign()
            if (shouldSign()) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            } else {
                signingConfig null
            }
        }

        dev {
            initWith debug
            // Signing and zip-aligning are skipped for prebuilt builds, but
            // performed for Godot gradle builds.
            zipAlignEnabled shouldZipAlign()
            if (shouldSign()) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            } else {
                signingConfig null
            }
        }

        release {
            // Signing and zip-aligning are skipped for prebuilt builds, but
            // performed for Godot gradle builds.
            zipAlignEnabled shouldZipAlign()
            if (shouldSign()) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            } else {
                signingConfig null
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['aidl']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        debug.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/debug', 'libs/debug/vulkan_validation_layers']
        dev.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/dev']
        release.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/release']
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            output.outputFileName = "android_${variant.name}.apk"
        }
    }
}

task copyAndRenameDebugApk(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/outputs/apk/debug/android_debug.apk"
    into getExportPath()
    rename "android_debug.apk", getExportFilename()
}

task copyAndRenameDevApk(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/outputs/apk/dev/android_dev.apk"
    into getExportPath()
    rename "android_dev.apk", getExportFilename()
}

task copyAndRenameReleaseApk(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/outputs/apk/release/android_release.apk"
    into getExportPath()
    rename "android_release.apk", getExportFilename()
}

task copyAndRenameDebugAab(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/outputs/bundle/debug/build-debug.aab"
    into getExportPath()
    rename "build-debug.aab", getExportFilename()
}

task copyAndRenameDevAab(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/outputs/bundle/dev/build-dev.aab"
    into getExportPath()
    rename "build-dev.aab", getExportFilename()
}

task copyAndRenameReleaseAab(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/outputs/bundle/release/build-release.aab"
    into getExportPath()
    rename "build-release.aab", getExportFilename()
}

/**
 * Used to validate the version of the Java SDK used for the Godot gradle builds.
 */
task validateJavaVersion {
    if (JavaVersion.current() != versions.javaVersion) {
        throw new GradleException("Invalid Java version ${JavaVersion.current()}. Version ${versions.javaVersion} is the required Java version for Godot gradle builds.")
    }
}

/*
When they're scheduled to run, the copy*AARToAppModule tasks generate dependencies for the 'app'
module, so we're ensuring the ':app:preBuild' task is set to run after those tasks.
 */
if (rootProject.tasks.findByPath("copyDebugAARToAppModule") != null) {
    preBuild.mustRunAfter(rootProject.tasks.named("copyDebugAARToAppModule"))
}
if (rootProject.tasks.findByPath("copyDevAARToAppModule") != null) {
    preBuild.mustRunAfter(rootProject.tasks.named("copyDevAARToAppModule"))
}
if (rootProject.tasks.findByPath("copyReleaseAARToAppModule") != null) {
    preBuild.mustRunAfter(rootProject.tasks.named("copyReleaseAARToAppModule"))
}


and config.gradle:
ext.versions = [
    androidGradlePlugin: '8.5.0',
    compileSdk         : 34,
    // Also update 'platform/android/export/export_plugin.cpp#OPENGL_MIN_SDK_VERSION'
    minSdk             : 21,
    // Also update 'platform/android/export/export_plugin.cpp#DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION'
    targetSdk          : 34,
    buildTools         : '34.0.0',
    kotlinVersion      : '1.9.20',
    fragmentVersion    : '1.6.2',
    nexusPublishVersion: '1.3.0',
    javaVersion        : JavaVersion.VERSION_21,
    // Also update 'platform/android/detect.py#get_ndk_version()' when this is updated.
    ndkVersion         : '23.2.8568313'

]

ext.getExportPackageName = { ->
    // Retrieve the app id from the project property set by the Godot build command.
    String appId = project.hasProperty("export_package_name") ? project.property("export_package_name") : ""
    // Check if the app id is valid, otherwise use the default.
    if (appId == null || appId.isEmpty()) {
        appId = "com.godot.game"
    }
    return appId
}

ext.getExportVersionCode = { ->
    String versionCode = project.hasProperty("export_version_code") ? project.property("export_version_code") : ""
    if (versionCode == null || versionCode.isEmpty()) {
        versionCode = "1"
    }
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(versionCode)
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
        return 1
    }
}

ext.getExportVersionName = { ->
    String versionName = project.hasProperty("export_version_name") ? project.property("export_version_name") : ""
    if (versionName == null || versionName.isEmpty()) {
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    return versionName
}

ext.getExportMinSdkVersion = { ->
    String minSdkVersion = project.hasProperty("export_version_min_sdk") ? project.property("export_version_min_sdk") : ""
    if (minSdkVersion == null || minSdkVersion.isEmpty()) {
        minSdkVersion = "$versions.minSdk"
    }
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(minSdkVersion)
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
        return versions.minSdk
    }
}

ext.getExportTargetSdkVersion = { ->
    String targetSdkVersion = project.hasProperty("export_version_target_sdk") ? project.property("export_version_target_sdk") : ""
    if (targetSdkVersion == null || targetSdkVersion.isEmpty()) {
        targetSdkVersion = "$versions.targetSdk"
    }
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(targetSdkVersion)
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
        return versions.targetSdk
    }
}

ext.getGodotEditorVersion = { ->
    String editorVersion = project.hasProperty("godot_editor_version") ? project.property("godot_editor_version") : ""
    if (editorVersion == null || editorVersion.isEmpty()) {
        // Try the library version first
        editorVersion = getGodotLibraryVersionName()

        if (editorVersion.isEmpty()) {
            // Fallback value.
            editorVersion = "custom_build"
        }
    }
    return editorVersion
}

ext.getGodotLibraryVersionCode = { ->
    String versionName = ""
    int versionCode = 1
    (versionName, versionCode) = getGodotLibraryVersion()
    return versionCode
}

ext.getGodotLibraryVersionName = { ->
    String versionName = ""
    int versionCode = 1
    (versionName, versionCode) = getGodotLibraryVersion()
    return versionName
}

ext.generateGodotLibraryVersion = { List<String> requiredKeys ->
    // Attempt to read the version from the `version.py` file.
    String libraryVersionName = ""
    int libraryVersionCode = 0

    File versionFile = new File("../../../version.py")
    if (versionFile.isFile()) {
        def map = [:]

        List<String> lines = versionFile.readLines()
        for (String line in lines) {
            String[] keyValue = line.split("=")
            String key = keyValue[0].trim()
            String value = keyValue[1].trim().replaceAll("\"", "")

            if (requiredKeys.contains(key)) {
                if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                    map[key] = value
                }
                requiredKeys.remove(key)
            }
        }

        if (requiredKeys.empty) {
            libraryVersionName = map.values().join(".")
            try {
                if (map.containsKey("status")) {
                    int statusCode = 0
                    String statusValue = map["status"]
                    if (statusValue == null) {
                        statusCode = 0
                    } else if (statusValue.startsWith("dev")) {
                        statusCode = 1
                    } else if (statusValue.startsWith("alpha")) {
                        statusCode = 2
                    } else if (statusValue.startsWith("beta")) {
                        statusCode = 3
                    } else if (statusValue.startsWith("rc")) {
                        statusCode = 4
                    } else if (statusValue.startsWith("stable")) {
                        statusCode = 5
                    } else {
                        statusCode = 0
                    }

                    libraryVersionCode = statusCode
                }

                if (map.containsKey("patch")) {
                    libraryVersionCode += Integer.parseInt(map["patch"]) * 10
                }

                if (map.containsKey("minor")) {
                    libraryVersionCode += (Integer.parseInt(map["minor"]) * 1000)
                }

                if (map.containsKey("major")) {
                    libraryVersionCode += (Integer.parseInt(map["major"]) * 100000)
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                libraryVersionCode = 1
            }
        }
    }

    if (libraryVersionName.isEmpty()) {
        // Fallback value in case we're unable to read the file.
        libraryVersionName = "custom_build"
    }

    if (libraryVersionCode == 0) {
        libraryVersionCode = 1
    }

    return [libraryVersionName, libraryVersionCode]
}

ext.getGodotLibraryVersion = { ->
    List<String> requiredKeys = ["major", "minor", "patch", "status", "module_config"]
    return generateGodotLibraryVersion(requiredKeys)
}

ext.getGodotPublishVersion = { ->
    List<String> requiredKeys = ["major", "minor", "patch", "status"]
    String versionName = ""
    int versionCode = 1
    (versionName, versionCode) = generateGodotLibraryVersion(requiredKeys)
    if (!versionName.endsWith("stable")) {
        versionName += "-SNAPSHOT"
    }
    return versionName
}

final String VALUE_SEPARATOR_REGEX = "\\|"

// get the list of ABIs the project should be exported to
ext.getExportEnabledABIs = { ->
    String enabledABIs = project.hasProperty("export_enabled_abis") ? project.property("export_enabled_abis") : "";
    if (enabledABIs == null || enabledABIs.isEmpty()) {
        enabledABIs = "armeabi-v7a|arm64-v8a|x86|x86_64|"
    }
    Set<String> exportAbiFilter = [];
    for (String abi_name : enabledABIs.split(VALUE_SEPARATOR_REGEX)) {
        if (!abi_name.trim().isEmpty()){
            exportAbiFilter.add(abi_name);
        }
    }
    return exportAbiFilter;
}

ext.getExportPath = {
    String exportPath = project.hasProperty("export_path") ? project.property("export_path") : ""
    if (exportPath == null || exportPath.isEmpty()) {
        exportPath = "."
    }
    return exportPath
}

ext.getExportFilename = {
    String exportFilename = project.hasProperty("export_filename") ? project.property("export_filename") : ""
    if (exportFilename == null || exportFilename.isEmpty()) {
        exportFilename = "godot_android"
    }
    return exportFilename
}

/**
 * Parse the project properties for the 'plugins_maven_repos' property and return the list
 * of maven repos.
 */
ext.getGodotPluginsMavenRepos = { ->
    Set<String> mavenRepos = []

    // Retrieve the list of maven repos.
    if (project.hasProperty("plugins_maven_repos")) {
        String mavenReposProperty = project.property("plugins_maven_repos")
        if (mavenReposProperty != null && !mavenReposProperty.trim().isEmpty()) {
            for (String mavenRepoUrl : mavenReposProperty.split(VALUE_SEPARATOR_REGEX)) {
                mavenRepos += mavenRepoUrl.trim()
            }
        }
    }

    return mavenRepos
}

/**
 * Parse the project properties for the 'plugins_remote_binaries' property and return
 * it for inclusion in the build dependencies.
 */
ext.getGodotPluginsRemoteBinaries = { ->
    Set<String> remoteDeps = []

    // Retrieve the list of remote plugins binaries.
    if (project.hasProperty("plugins_remote_binaries")) {
        String remoteDepsList = project.property("plugins_remote_binaries")
        if (remoteDepsList != null && !remoteDepsList.trim().isEmpty()) {
            for (String dep: remoteDepsList.split(VALUE_SEPARATOR_REGEX)) {
                remoteDeps += dep.trim()
            }
        }
    }
    return remoteDeps
}

/**
 * Parse the project properties for the 'plugins_local_binaries' property and return
 * their binaries for inclusion in the build dependencies.
 */
ext.getGodotPluginsLocalBinaries = { ->
    Set<String> binDeps = []

    // Retrieve the list of local plugins binaries.
    if (project.hasProperty("plugins_local_binaries")) {
        String pluginsList = project.property("plugins_local_binaries")
        if (pluginsList != null && !pluginsList.trim().isEmpty()) {
            for (String plugin : pluginsList.split(VALUE_SEPARATOR_REGEX)) {
                binDeps += plugin.trim()
            }
        }
    }

    return binDeps
}

ext.getDebugKeystoreFile = { ->
    String keystoreFile = project.hasProperty("debug_keystore_file") ? project.property("debug_keystore_file") : ""
    if (keystoreFile == null || keystoreFile.isEmpty()) {
        keystoreFile = "."
    }
    return keystoreFile
}

ext.hasCustomDebugKeystore = { ->
    File keystoreFile = new File(getDebugKeystoreFile())
    return keystoreFile.isFile()
}

ext.getDebugKeystorePassword = { ->
    String keystorePassword = project.hasProperty("debug_keystore_password") ? project.property("debug_keystore_password") : ""
    if (keystorePassword == null || keystorePassword.isEmpty()) {
        keystorePassword = "android"
    }
    return keystorePassword
}

ext.getDebugKeyAlias = { ->
    String keyAlias = project.hasProperty("debug_keystore_alias") ? project.property("debug_keystore_alias") : ""
    if (keyAlias == null || keyAlias.isEmpty()) {
        keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
    }
    return keyAlias
}

ext.getReleaseKeystoreFile = { ->
    String keystoreFile = project.hasProperty("release_keystore_file") ? project.property("release_keystore_file") : ""
    if (keystoreFile == null || keystoreFile.isEmpty()) {
        keystoreFile = "."
    }
    return keystoreFile
}

ext.getReleaseKeystorePassword = { ->
    String keystorePassword = project.hasProperty("release_keystore_password") ? project.property("release_keystore_password") : ""
    return keystorePassword
}

ext.getReleaseKeyAlias = { ->
    String keyAlias = project.hasProperty("release_keystore_alias") ? project.property("release_keystore_alias") : ""
    return keyAlias
}

ext.isAndroidStudio = { ->
    def sysProps = System.getProperties()
    return sysProps != null && sysProps['idea.platform.prefix'] != null
}

ext.shouldZipAlign = { ->
    String zipAlignFlag = project.hasProperty("perform_zipalign") ? project.property("perform_zipalign") : ""
    if (zipAlignFlag == null || zipAlignFlag.isEmpty()) {
        if (isAndroidStudio()) {
            zipAlignFlag = "true"
        } else {
            zipAlignFlag = "false"
        }
    }
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(zipAlignFlag)
}

ext.shouldSign = { ->
    String signFlag = project.hasProperty("perform_signing") ? project.property("perform_signing") : ""
    if (signFlag == null || signFlag.isEmpty()) {
        if (isAndroidStudio()) {
            signFlag = "true"
        } else {
            signFlag = "false"
        }
    }
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(signFlag)
}

ext.shouldNotStrip = { ->
    return isAndroidStudio() || project.hasProperty("doNotStrip")
}

/**
 * Whether to use the legacy convention of compressing all .so files in the APK.
 *
 * For more background, see:
 * - https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-3-6-0-release-notes#extractNativeLibs
 * - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704840
 */
ext.shouldUseLegacyPackaging = { ->
    int minSdk = getExportMinSdkVersion()
    if (minSdk < 23) {
        // Enforce the default behavior for compatibility with device running api < 23
        return true
    }

    String legacyPackagingFlag = project.hasProperty("compress_native_libraries") ? project.property("compress_native_libraries") : ""
    if (legacyPackagingFlag != null && !legacyPackagingFlag.isEmpty()) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(legacyPackagingFlag)
    }

    // Default behavior for minSdk >= 23
    return false
}


i tried replacing the android build template with a new one to solve the problem but it didn't work
i searched the internet and couldn't find a clear answer
note*
My English is not good so can you explain what you are saying in simple language(i am trying to improve my language level)
what should I do because the problem has been with me for two days

There is no version 8.5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin yet. See repo.
Try replacing with the latest stable version
androidGradlePlugin: '8.3.2'

