# App not installed error when using app center distribution for android

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

Keep getting this error when I try to install the downloaded sdk. Any ideas?

The app builds and tests without errors. I get no detailed error message, only `App not installed`

How can I get a more detailed error message? Any ideas?

My very first build worked, so I guess it could be the version number not matching up. However, I have tried harcoding the number, still won't install:

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rgcalendar"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 23
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Go to file - settings- Instant run - uncheck the instant run option. Now build your apk and check.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: same issue. did you find solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was running into this issue with an App Center build on a Galaxy S8. I had tried uninstalling the app, restarting the phone and toggling the `allow Unknown Sources switch`, but **the thing that fixed it for me was turning off Play Protect in the Google Play store.** While previous builds had asked me to bypass Play Protect, this build just gave me the *"App not installed"* error.

To turn Play Protect off:

1. Open the Play Store
2. Tap the menu in the top left
3. Tap `Play Protect`
4. Turn off `Scan device for security threats`

You'll probably want to turn this back on if you're using a personal device.

Comment: Switched off Unknown Sources and Play Protect, but still seeing this.

Comment: I am also still getting this error

Answer (score 3):

From:
[App not installed error on android 11 device from appcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68125269/app-not-installed-error-on-android-11-device-from-appcenter)

Re-uploading the existing keystore on appcenter has resolved the issue

Answer (score 3):

### `android:extractNativeLibs="true"`

in **`AndroidManifest.xml`** file fixed the problem for me.

```
<application
    // ...
    android:extractNativeLibs="true"
```

**Notes**:

- I got this error when building with App Center and all the signing was handled by app center.
- **For easier debugging just drag and drop the `apk` file in the android emulator.
  Your will get a more detailed message why the app is not installed.**
- Previously I tried all the Play protect things and checked the `build.gradle` file contains no release info in signingConfigs and that there's no `signingConfig` in `buildTypes.release` just as described in the other answers from this page.
- The fix was suggested to me by the app center support team.
  They usually respond in less than 8 hours. In my case I got an
  answers in less than 2h since sending them the email.
- This question is possibly linked to:
  [How to fix App not installed error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608783/how-to-fix-app-not-installed-error-in-android/70599488)

Answer (score 1):

Are you signing the build yourself? If you are, look in the app/build.gradle file.

Search for buildTypes and look at release.

Remove `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug`.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug // <-- REMOVE THIS LINE
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I had a previous version of the app installed on my phone. Uninstalling the older version and trying again made the message go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as I directly uploaded the apk creataed by the Run-Button in Android Studio. Creating a new debug apk by ./gradlew assembleDebug solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem today. I uploaded app for iPad on App centre. But when i opened the website to install app in iPad, it didn't let me open the app. Sometimes when it allowed it was considering iPad safari as Mac Safari and didn't give me install option.

So what i did, set my default browser Google Chrome and i clicked the install button from email i received. It worked. App centre gave me an option to install the app.