# App not installed error on android 11 device from appcenter

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am working on **Xamarin.Forms** app. After changing **targetSdkVersion** to **30** and building app on appcenter with latest sdk(11.1) available, I am getting error `App not installed` only on **android 11** device.
If I change **targetSdkVersion** back to **29** and build the app on appcenter then I am able to install the app on **android 11** device.

Got more detail when installing apk on emulator :

```
The APK failed to install.
Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Scanning Failed.: No signature found in package of version 2 or newer for package "*packagename*"
```

Do I need to update my keystore ? if yes, how can I update it ?

Comment: Re-uploading the existing keystore on appcenter has resolved the issue

Comment: Congrats, and thanks for your support for xamarin.

Comment: Same thing happened to our build. Re-uploading the keystore seems to have fixed it (also disabled app bundle for the internal build, which I had enabled while troubleshooting this issue, and it remained broken until I disabled it).

Answer (score 3):

Re-uploading the existing keystore on appcenter has resolved the issue, worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I faced with latest Android version. In `appcenter` select the app, goto `settings` and

```
remove existing keystore and upload keystore again
```