# "App not installed" trying to install signed-apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, signed-apk

I'm facing with **App not installed** error on different devices - some I have not even installed **debug apk** before! -So it's not same package name-.

I'm able to install the apk by changing the alias of generated key, but the apk only install once and after deleting the app on my phone, it won't install again!

I've tried all of the solutions I've found on similar questions but non works.

- I've tried changing **version code** and **version name**
- I've tried checking only V1 or V2 and both
- android:testOnly="false"
- android.injected.testOnly=false
- minifyEnabled false
- and build variants is set to release

I have tested on more than 10 devices from different brands -samsung, sony, huawei-

I'm using android studio 3.3 and Gradle 3.3.0 and

- compileSdkVersion 28
- minSdkVersion 22
- targetSdkVersion 28

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: If you go on the device settings, does your app show the with the option "uninstall for all users"?

Comment: No, and I have tried with phones which the app has not been installed before so it shouldn't be about guest user.

Comment: Ok, do you get any error code? Like, apk bit aligned?

Comment: No error, signed apk installs using android studio. I just realized that when I install the apk from android studio, it installs how many times that I want. But when I'm installing the app from let's say Whats app, I can only install it once. After that, "App not installed" shown up again!

Comment: Oh I see. I thought this was just installing from Android studio. Sorry I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought this was just installing from Android studio. Sorry I don't know what's happening.

Comment: DId you manage to solve this problem? Happening the same here

Comment: @choquero70 Turns out the only way is to submit a form to Google. It took me about two weeks last time and problem solved without any feedback from Google!
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51233170/4798168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might still be looking for an answer, here it is

a) You should [submit your app for google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals) and after a while, about 10-14 days, the problem will be solved. [More info...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57918081/4798168)

b) Turning off PlayProtect which is not the correct answer but it can keep you going.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too!

Why?

When I used 'targetSdkVersion 28' my apk not installed. only build apk(s) solved my problem.

Comment: It seems like it is a policy by google. You should submit your app into the link below and after a while, about 10-14 days, the problem will be solved. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals