# Can't install my application to my phone when sign release apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

I try to install my app to my phone but I get app not installed error  when sign as release apk 
 this is my gradle for app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
signingConfigs {
    signingConfigs {
        keyAlias 'newv'
        keyPassword 'key'
        storeFile file('/dir')
        storePassword 'pass'
   }}
```

my app have two  module  and below this file that i wan from package options

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/mips/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/mips64/libc++_shared.so'
}
dexOptions {
    maxProcessCount 8
    javaMaxHeapSize "1g"
    preDexLibraries true
}

compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sadeem.mobiletv"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        jniDebuggable false
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile project(':libvlc')
compile project(':api')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

my gradle module one is

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
```

artifacts.add("default", file('api-release.aar'))

and two  is

configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('libvlc-3.0.0-null.aar'))

i do't why not install after release apk  any one help

Comment: Try to use  "v2SigningEnabled false" as described here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2

If it does not work - then generate apk manually, I suppose here is your answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: Also "signingConfigs {  signingConfigs { " looks a little bit strange.

Comment: i used it  but give me the same error app un install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's Android version issue. Try to select both the *Signature Version* check boxes while generating signed APK file i.e. *v1* and *v2*. OR Try to uninstall earlier versions of your app (like debug APKs).

Comment: i have only one version

Comment: Check for the v1 and v2 in Signature Version.

Comment: how i check give me example please

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that on your phone debug apk is installed. Please uninstall the debug apk and then install debug apk.

Comment: i am unistall  debug apk but give me the same error