# App not installed android studio

Tags: android

I am developing an app for a long time and now I'm trying to install generated apk on my phone, but there is error occurs. But it works fine when I run it on emulator or wi-fi adb connection with the phone. I'm already read a lot of manuals, but nothing helps me yet. I have no slightest idea why it's happening. 
Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="ru.scapegoats.checkers">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activity.game.Game" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.main.Main" />
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.bluetooth.BluetoothMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.main.Main" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.session.SessionActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.main.Main" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.createsession.CreateSessionActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.internet.InternetMenu" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.properties.Properties" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.main.Main" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.internet.InternetMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.main.Main" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.autorization.AutorizationActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.main.Main" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.registration.RegistrationActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.main.Main" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.main.Main" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.scapegoats.checkers"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}
ext {
    androidSupportVersion = "27.0.1"
    gmsVersion = "12.0.1"
    retrofitVersion = "2.1.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:${retrofitVersion}"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

I'm tried to run the app on different devices but error always the same.
[image: https://vk.com/photo232340670_456239622]

Comment: Can you also add the error description?

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android  @Andrew

Comment: do have older/same version of app installed?

Comment: @Andrew make sure you've uninstalled older versions [for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703571/3789527)

Comment: Working for me
Go to Build> Build Apk(s)
wait few seconds and pop up will be show in bottom right[Click locate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I8ei.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed complileSdkVersion to 28 and now it's installs fine.

Comment: where this setting lies?

Answer (score 2):

add `android:testOnly="false"` and `android:debuggable="true"` in your manifest section

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:testOnly="false"
    android:debuggable="true">
```

after this clean and Rebuild your project and try to install your apk again.

hope it will work..!! it works for me.

Comment: doesn't help :((

Comment: Reason for this error:-https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-some-APK-files-which-shows-app-not-installed-when-I-installed-normally

Comment: go to settings → Applications → Just Toggle on next to “ Unknown Sources” app option.

Comment: my others apps installed on my phone without problems

Answer (score 1):

I had changed my LAUNCHER activity to exported=false by mistake. Then removed it and fixed :).

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Build Bundle (s) / APK (s) -> Build APK (s)