# Android Emulator AMD Threadripper

Tags: android, emulation, amd-processor

I see that Android Studio now supports AMD, I have managed to get the emulator working and it installed apks from the play store fine, but whenever I try to download and install an apk I get

> APK NOT INSTALLED.

How can I fix this? I am very new to emulators and would appreciate any help offered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO!  Not sure but lets get clarified..are you using Genymotion's Emulator?