# Made a new app to replace old one getting app not installed

Tags: android, android-keystore

I made a new app that supposed to replace the old one ,
here's what I did :

- Used the same package name
- Increased versionCode
- Used the same Key(JKS file)

I tried the Key in all 3 variations  ( V1\V2\V1+V2 )

and still it's giving me

> App Not Installed

Any ideas what am I missing ?

Comment: Have you checked these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android?

Comment: try using adb install <file name.apk> , it will give better error results. Like what is the problem.

Comment: @nkalra0123 the Error is [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install my.packge without first uninstalling.]

Comment: @ADM I have checked it wasn't relevent to this case

Comment: @nkalra0123 help did it , found out the old one was debug mode that's why it didn't work , it also important to notice that the V1\V2 didn't matter