# APK File works in android emulator but won't install on my device

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to Android Studio (downloaded it yesterday on my Windows 7 machine) and just finished creating an app using Kotlin. It works properly on the Android Emulator, but when I build a signed APK file and try installing it on my Samsung S7 (Android 8.0.0) phone it shows the mysterious error "App not installed".

I noticed there's a red X mark near MainActivity in the top bar, maybe it has something to do with the problem? It doesn't prevent me from building...

[image: Red X Screenshot]

Previous builds of the same app installed properly. The only thing I changed before it started breaking is the location of the AVD folder (using [this](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/761-move-android-studio-avd-folder-to-a-new-location)) from the C drive to the D drive, since I ran out of memory there. I deleted all virtual devices, created the environment variable then created the virtual devices again.

Things I already tried without any luck:

- The top 5 solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)
- Deleting debug.keystore
- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Changing the build variant to "Release"

EDIT: I created a new project and copied my scripts to there, and it now works properly. Not really a solution since this took a lot of time, but it solved the problem.

Comment: There should be some information in the logcat regarding that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should have to create new sample project and check it will be working or not**

Comment: I created a new project and copied my scripts to there, and it now works properly. Not really a solution since this took a lot of time, but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have install apk before in your device you can not install it again

For fix that

**1)** You can uninstall app from device and reinstall from apk.

**2)** You can change **versionCode** in build.gradle(app)

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId your_package_name   
    versionCode 2 //try to increase every time
    versionName "1.0.0" //no need to change but better change it
    //other codes
}
```

Comment: @Bip901 did you use local database (sqlite) in your project?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the MainActivity(with X mark)
2. A dropdown will appear
3. Select your application Module (By Default it is `app`)
4. Run the Project (It should install the apk and run on your device)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I selected "App", but it, too, has a red X mark on it. I built the APK again with "App" selected, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by delete `.iml` file from your project directory and rebuild project

Have you restart your system after updating location of **AVD** ?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted my system after updating the AVD location. Just tried deleting the .iml file and rebuilding, and unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: then you should have to create new sample project and check it will be working or not

Comment: You should convert this comment into an answer, that's what I ended up doing

Comment: @Bip901 i have added the new answer