# App not installed! Error while installing apk from android studio build

Tags: java, android-studio

After generating signed apks via android studio, when installing the released apk, phone is showing the error:

> App not installed

I am facing this issue in this app. I was *already working* on it and installed such apks same as i did with it to install.

I'd already tried those:

- The app is free from all bugs/error
- tried and removed the catch
- checked device compatibility
- Tried all 3 possibilities of apk signatures[i.e. with only V1(Jar signatures) , only V2(full apk signatures), and both too]

The app is working fluently on the emulator and the apk is installed on phone too via studio BUT NOT installable with the released apk file.

Comment: Possible duplicate ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Answer (score 4):

To protect android from maleware it is not allowed to update an app that has a different signing-key (debug-build uses a different signing key than release)

Uninstall previous debug-build-app before installing release-build-app.

Comment: yes, i'm done with that. But issue had not resolved. Suggest me some tips to get my released apk installable

Answer (score 2):

To cope up with such situation, i found a way: *just delete previously released apk from android studio folder and rebuild and then share to install the apk*.
It worked well for me. 
Thankyou everyone who suggested their possible solutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but have resolved it. If you are using dual profiles on the same phone, then you have to uninstall the App on all profiles, so that you can reinstall the APK you want to. This is applicable for non-PlayStore installs. The scenario that I had is this: on main profile I had installed from a non-PlayStore APK & the second profile had the install from the PlayStore. When I tried to install a new non-PlayStore APK, the error -APP NOT INSTALLED- kept coming up because the 2nd profile on the same phone had an updated APK that was of a later version that I was trying to install. Upon uninstalling the App for all profiles, I was able to install the non-PlayStore APK version that I had downloaded.
PS: I did not like the latest upgrade of an APP & proffered the older version, which I had downloaded from the net to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Invalid Caches/restart**
Go to File-> Invalid Caches/Restart

or if You are running your app in you android phone instead of emulator then check setting of your phone,
Go to Developer Option and enable,
**Verify apps over USB**
then run again
I hope this will help you!
Thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned that I was using this stuff from quite long time but this issue raised for now. So, it is obvious that i'm done with this stuff. Thanks for your answer. Please suggest some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your manifest and make sure you have given "android:exported=true" attribute to your launching activity.

```
<activity
android:name=".StarterActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
android:exported="true">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```