# "App not installed" when install singed apk

Tags: android, apk

I have generated a signed APK for my application

here is the `build.gradle`

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.test_drivers"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have checked both V1 and V2. The app is installed perfectly in version 8 but not in version 9.

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: check if you already have a debug build on the phone that you are trying to install the signed apk. If the phone already has debug or release build(unsigned), uninstall that build then install the signed apk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Comment: @AkhilSoman I have already checked that

Comment: @RicardoA.  I checked it , that's why I'm asking

Comment: Can you see any errors in the logcat when you try to install? THere should be a message explaining why it cannot install.