# Google Play App Signing - how to verify if the local keystore is correct?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-signing

I published an aab format application in Google Play Console.
How to verify if the local keystore is the correct one with the one uploaded on Google Play Console?

Is this correct?
Google Play Console > Release management > App signing > Upload certificate
There are 3 certificat fingerprints: MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256.

They match all with the fingerprint of the local keystore file.
Is the local keystore correct?

If yes, I don't know why I cannot update my application. The version code published in PlayStore is `3`. All three artifacts `1` `2` `3` are both aab in Play Console.
In local, I have: `1.apk`, `1.aab`, `2.apk`, `2.aab`, `3.aab` but NOT `3.apk`

Test 1 (ok): The update from `1.apk` > `2.apk` > `4.apk` work.

Test 2 (ok):
Version `3` was on `Beta` then passed to `Production` is downloaded from Play Console.
By using `bundletool`: `3.aab` > apks > install on new phone > update to local file 4.apk work.

Test 3 (failed): 
New phone > install `3` from Play Store > can not update to 4.apk `App not installed` (the version we are testing) ???
How is that possible?

Thank you.

Update 2 from adb log:
`installd: 
Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl544123587.tmp: No such file or directory
Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1822356369.tmp: No such file or directory`

Update 3: apk files are signed by `signingConfig` field in android block.

Update 4: 
from another phone:
`installd:
Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl2014632873.tmp: No such file or directory
Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl2014632873.tmp: No such file or directory`

Comment: What is going on when you try to update? What is the error? How are you trying to update? Please explain more.

Comment: Hi, I added the error message = `App not installed`, please tell me if there is somethings I can do. Thanks.

Comment: Tell me your about your apk/aab Signature Version? Which one you use?

Comment: I use `signingConfig` field in android block. I dont what what version it is :(
I updated the question too.

Comment: I think that is your problem. I will post it as answer so you will understand how it can be possible your app to behave differently on other phone and give you App Not Installed error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are:

- App signing key (1) - managed by Google, is Inaccessible
- Upload key (2) - is managed by us

If we use App Signing by Google Play, the (1) may be different with the (2) that causes the `App not installed` problem when we use (2) to sign app.

(2) as its name is only for `uploading`.
You may have (1) and (2) identicals.

Use fingerprints to verify whether the key is correct.

My problem was that: the first time I did not recognize that Play Console generate another key (1) for signing but not the key (2).

If you do not upload (1), you can not obtain it to sign/test on local (without Play Console). We have to use Play Console for testing version update.

Answer (score 1):

You can encounter **App not installed** error when trying to install an apk/aab on some devices with some OS version and on others with different OS version the apk/aab gets installed like a charm.

The problem is the **signature versions** you use when building your signed apk.

[image: Generate Signed APK]

Check both **V2 (Full APK Signature)** and **V1 Jar Signature** and after that you will be able to successfully install your signed apk/aab on the device that you couldn't before.

**Example:** *On Galaxy S4 mini with Android 4.4.2 if you forget to check the "V1 signature" the app cannot be installed on the device. After checking V1, the apk gets installed.*

Comment: I signed another build with both options enabled but still the same result :(

Comment: There are multiple reasons for APP NOT INSTALLED error. The one I posted is the most common one. Please refer to this threat and try the various suggestions. Hope you will find the solution it fits.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android