# Trying to install app_debug.apk on phone and get app not installed

Tags: android, android-studio, build

Part of a course I'm trying for Android Studio, I have to submit the `app_debug.apk` file. But for some reason I can't seem to install it on my two phones (Galaxy and xiaomi). I get "App not installed". What I tried:

1. Build->clean.
2. Build->Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)->Build APK(s).
3. Click 'locate'.
4. Move the app_debug.apk file to my phone.
5. Install it.

It does not work and I get "App not installed". The strange thing is when I connect the phone with a USB cable and install the app though Android Studio, it works great. What could be the issue?

Comment: Check your phone storage. It happens if it is full. Also, check the target api version.

Comment: I have quite a lot of space on both phones I tried. Target API is 16 so it should work

Comment: Try to remove installed APK, and re-install it.

Comment: many possible reasons, I had same when the app was already installed, so try removing it, and check this out for many more possible reasons https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-some-APK-files-which-shows-app-not-installed-when-I-installed-normally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe there isn't a step by step guide for this.

There's multiple reasons for this to happen.

Something you may wanna check

- Have you authorized installing apk from outside playstore?
- Do you have a previus version of the apk already installed? Delete it and try installing
- Try genering a release apk
- On your android manifest check if there's a "testonly=true" line. Try removing it.
- Do you have available space? Check it on settings