# How to generate a signed apk in android studio?

Tags: android, apk

I created a signed apk .

But , when I install it comes like this.
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Comment: @ADM I tried but it not work.

Comment: Are there any logs?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall your app completely and install again

```
Settings -> Apps -> Click on your App. 

In App info page at the action bar menu there will be an option " Uninstall for All users " click that.
```

Your app will be completely uninstalled and now you can try installing the new version.

Also In application check the unknown sources option

Comment: @Poorvaja when you were testing the app there could be earlier versions which doesn't show up in the app drawer. In the android go to the app info of your particular app and uninstall for all the users. This could be because its signed with a different signature.

Comment: I searched the option app info

But , I can't find this.  

where I can find "app info" ?

Comment: What is the android version you are running @Poorvaja

Comment: android studio Version 4.0.1 .

Comment: The avd version of android

Comment: I am using physical device with android os 10

Comment: You might have manage apps or Apps in the settings. Find the app and uninstall it.

Comment: Can you give a screen shot?

Comment: It varies in name for each type of os. Miui has manage apps in apps. In oxygen os it will be under apps. Depends on the os. You have to search for it

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same problem and in my case it's because I don't generate a `signed APK`

To Generate Signed APK first you need `keystore` file. You can create keystore with Android Studio with these steps :

1. Select `Build` in Menu bar
2. Select `Generate Signed Bundle or APK`
3. Select `APK` or `Android App Bundle`. Choose based on what you need, if you don't know what to choose just choose `APK`
4. Click `Create New` button under `key store path` textbox
5. Fill all the information needed

   - Be aware that there's  2 password textbox. The first one is `keystore passowrd` and the second one is `key password`. It' s different thing and save them on notepad or whatever so you don't forget it
   - Also remember the path where you save the `keystore` file

After creating `keystore` file now we begin to create the signed APK

1. Follow the first 3 steps form creating `keystore` file until you asked to choose `keystore`
2. Now for keystore we choose the one that we have been created by clicking `choose existing` button

   - Fill in the `keystore password` and `key password`
3. Select you destination folder for the APK, and for build variant you can choose `release`