# Flutter app not installed from apk or appbundle, works well on emulator

Tags: flutter, corrupt

My flutter app is running perfectly fine in the emulator. It is also running well when I run as --release in an x86_64 emulator.

But when I create an APK, and install on a real device, it says "App not installed." I even created an app bundle and published the app on Play Store, but that also doesn't install on devices.

Info:

```
Flutter 1.22.3, Dart 2.10.3

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.9.0 <3.0.0"
```

I have run flutter upgrade

and I get 2 warnings during build:

```
Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

included in my app/build.gradle file

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

defaultConfig {
    .......
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

What could be wrong? I am lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Comment: try to install apk file using ```adb install /path/to.apk```. Then you can find what is the error

Comment: @user13775947 Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

try to use flutter clean and run this command again

Comment: did that several times, no luck :(