# Apk not installed error when extracting the apk file from /data/app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm programming a basic app to share apk files between two devices the problem is when I extract an installed app base file (base.apk) from **/data/app** I get "App not installed" error when trying to install this apk file ... I even tried apps like ApkExtractor but I get the same error ... this problem only happened on **android 10** , the app works file on android 6 .... any ideas why is this happening and how to fix it ??

Comment: Did you try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: @HarisDautović this is not my issue .. my issue is that when I copy the base.apk file from /data/app I cant install that apk file

Comment: `works file on android 6 .... ` What do you mean with those `....`?

Comment: works fine on Android 6...

Comment: works fine ** .. sorry for the mistake ... I mean when I tested the same app in android 6.0 the app worked fine and I was able to install the apk file