# "Application not installed" android on emulator or physical device?

Tags: android

When I run my application "RUN" on the emulator it works. But when I manually install the APK I get an error message "***Application not installed***" any idea please?

Comment: try uninstalling old apk before installing new one

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android) (it could be any number of issues, but probably you have a previous version of the app installed)

Answer (score 0):

Disable minifyEnable. then generate build

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is very unlikely to help.