# “App is not installed” error occurs when trying to sideload APK from external sources

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

****Requirement**:** "adb install" is not possible due to USB write restrictions on my machine. So, I can only install the .apk file via phone memory.

****Issue**:** “App is not installed” error occurs when trying to sideload APK from external sources (ask file from internal/external phone memory).

**Device Info**: Samsung M30S [Android 11]

**Please Note:** I checked below

- The phone has sufficient Storage
- Installation from unknown sources in device settings is allowed
- Did clean installed not the update
- Tried to install on different devices (2 devices)

Tried almost all available options which I found over the internet. Some are as below, but none worked:

- Disabling Google Play Protect
- Resetting App Preferences
- Tried APKs created with different ABIs

One possible reason could be the corrupted app, but I am not sure about it as this is getting installed on the emulator and a few days back same was getting installed on phone as well. Even the older .apk files are getting installed properly but not the new ones.

Any help/leads in this are highly appreciated.

Comment: You can get help with your coding. I see no code.

Comment: The code base is too heavy to post here. Moreover I don't think any code sharing is required here.

Comment: APK Editor [https://www.digitbin.com/apk-editor-download/] as suggested by many over the internet also not helping.

Comment: Code base too heavy? Strange. Code to install an apk has been posted before.

Comment: @blackapps As said in my question, I am ownloading .apk to my device's My files. And then installing it manually (double click on .apk file). So, which code do you want here?

Comment: You are on a coding site. If you are not a programmer you should look for another forum to post your problem. Wrong place here.

Comment: @blackapps As said, I have tried the solutions found over the web, but none worked. This is one from ur coding site as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android 
Anyways, Thanks for ur time. I will find the solution....I am a programmer :)