# Flutter apk not installing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to install my apk on an android device except only for this apk. I am using the `flutter build apk` command to generate apk. After sharing apk to some device it was getting app not installed as shown in [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e632.jpg).

I am using VSCode and here I am sharing the flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1466], locale en-US)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    [√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    [√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Other apk's are working fine except this one on my device.

Comment: did app is already install on that devices ? If yes then please uninstall it and then try to reinstall it

Comment: yes, I already tried that. it's not working @AR

Comment: @GHPrakash Please try to change your package name

Comment: Ok. I will try and let You know @AR

Comment: @GHPrakash : Is your device running on android -12 ? if yes then add this attribute  android:exported="true" to the activity

Comment: @GHPrakash and check it out this link also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713171/11404883

Comment: no use @AR by changing package name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try all these steps:**

1. Make sure that you have enough storage space
2. Enable the installation from Unknown Sources
3. Make sure that the APK file isn’t corrupted or incomplete
4. try to clear cache of package installer and reboot
5. Check if the app is already installed in your device.
6. Check if the play protect option is enabled, if it is then turn off it in play store from navigation drawer.
7. Make sure “applicationId” in build.gradle file is unique.
8. **Just go to the Settings --> Apps --> Click on your App. ---> In App info page at the action bar menu there will be an option called " Uninstall for All users " click that.**

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue is occur when you transfer apk file directly via any messaging platform or USB ... Some time it will happen and apk file will corrupt.. So I suggest to create a link for distribution of your app..

You can upload your apk in `Google drive` or use `Firebase App Distribution` or just `WeTransfer`. And Generate the link and then transfer that link....

Comment: I am using Firebase App Distribution only.

Comment: Is there any other way?