# Maui App how to install on Android phone with APK file

Tags: android, installation, build, apk, maui

### EDIT: How to install Android app using just APK file

*This worked as of **10/13/2023***

Here's how to do it, step by step:

**Step 1: build your APK file**
IF you don't have Visual Studio's CLI (Command Line Interface) tools installed, install them, as you'll need to use the command [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish).

Make sure your project is cleaned.  If there is a `Release` folder in your `bin` folder, delete it.

Open a command prompt to the folder that contains the `.sln` file for your project and run this command:
`dotnet publish -c Release -r android-arm64 -p:PackageFormat=Apk -f net7.0-android --sc true`

If you get errors/warnings, read about the "dotnet publish" command in the article linked above; what I show above is what worked for me after tinkering with the command.  For example, if you're not using .NET 7.0, you won't want the argument `net7.0-android` after the `-f` flag, and if you want to release on more than just Android, you'll probably have to include more frameworks than just Android.

Be patient with the command as well.  It might take a good five minutes.  Let it sit.

Anyways, you'll end up with file in the `bin\Release` folder of your project.  In my case, the APK folder was located here:
`bin\Release\net7.0-android\android-arm64`.

In fact, I got two APK files, one was signed and the other one wasn't.

### Step 2: Set up your phone so that it can run an APK file

Update the phone's OS.  It's gotta be the latest-greatest.  It's easy to ignore this step, but it tripped me up, so do it anyways.

Get a file manager app for your phone.  You'll end up using it a lot, anyways.  I paid two bucks for "File Manager +" (remember, if you're not paying for the app you're not getting the product because *you* are the product).

Next, even though we're not going to use Google Play, we have to mess with it.  First, update it.  Go to:
`Google Play >> your profile >> Settings >> General >> scroll to the bottom of the screen >> About >> Play store version >> Update Play Store`

After that, turn off play protect.  Go to:
`Google Play >> your profile >> Play Protect >> Turn off Play protect scanning`

### Step 3: Install the APK file

Plug your phone into your computer via USB.  Now you have access to the phone's file system via your PC's file system.  Move the *signed* APK file from your PC to the *Downloads* folder on your phone (I'm not sure if the specific folder matters, but this worked for me).

After that you can unplug the phone from your PC, and -- using the file manager app you just installed -- navigate to the signed APK file and click it.  You should get a wizard that allows you to install the app.

Comment: disable Google Play Protect.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: I turned it off, restarted the phone, but I still get the error message "App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone".

Comment: I attempting to install the signed APK.  You think that could be it?  I'll try installing the unsigned one...

Comment: Just to be specific, to turn it off I went to the Google Play store, clicked on my profile, went to "Play Protect", settings, and turned off "scan apps with play protect".

Comment: I get different error messages depending on whether I try the signed APK or not.  The unsigned says "invalid app", the signed says "incompatible app".

Comment: Jason, this might be it:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/app-development/how-to-build-maui-to-apk/m-p/2997645

Comment: Got it!  I will update my question with the answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: Turning off 'Play Protect' NOT recommended.

Step 1:
Change from Debug to Release
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSLFW.png

Step 2:
Press F5 or Ctrl+F5

Step 3:
Go to Project->bin->Release and then android Folder
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYhqL.png

Step 4:
Find the file with apk extension having name with "signed" i.e. com.companyname.xxxx-Signed.apk

Step 5:
Copy above file and install.

Enjoy :)